# Library that Record from Audio Devices and Write to Disk

Tags: c++, wav, microphone, portaudio, aiff

I am looking for a cross-platform C++ library (if not, one for Windows and one for Macintosh) that records from a selected audio devices and write to disk in one of a common formats/containers.

Before I was doing recording with portaudio, but the library does not support it and that I have to manually format it myself. I have also looked at openal and libsndfile. And, ffmpeg looks complicated and does not offer me enough abstraction (in my opinion). Juce looks good, but there might a licensing issue if I decide to use it.

Comment: Voted to close, choosing the following option as the reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion in closing this question. I was serious about this question and thought that it was objective (selecting audio device and recording to disk in a playable container by most media players) though I am asking for a library. Writing audio to disk and conforming to a specification is no easy task and may not be desirable option for some businesses or purposes.

Comment: I don't doubt your seriousness for a moment. That doesn't discount the fact however, that you've asked for a library recommendation. A type of question which is, as I quoted, "off topic". The rules aren't personal, nor was my vote to close the question. Same rules go for you, me and everyone right up to Jon Skeet. The point is, while this is in my opinion a clear and well-formed question - it's not one suited to S.O, that's all. :)